# Get element button in modal react with jest?

Tags: reactjs

I have created a form in reactjs and when a user click a submit button my app will display a modal confirm.
I have to write a unit test jest/testing-library for this

```
fireEvent.click(getByTestId("submitButton"));

fireEvent.click(getByTestId("confirmButton"));
```

It's have an error when I get confirmButton.

```
fireEvent.click(getByTestId("confirmButton"));
```

How i fix it?

Comment: Can you show us the whole test-describe block? Because judging by the provided code nothing can be assumed.

Comment: library can't find that element

Comment: It does not find the element by its ID?

Comment: yes, it can't find the confirmButton

Comment: Then, I would suggest adding this on your button: <button data-testid='confirmButton'> </button>

Comment: And after that on your test suite, you can get it as such: 

const confirmButton = getByTestId(/confirmbutton/i);
fireEvent.click(confirmButton);

Comment: i'm already settled data-tested id for the confirmButton,

Comment: Do I need await for submit button when confirm modal display

Comment: I believe you are using jest with the React Testing Library. The main goal of RTL is not to mock functionality, but to check if the components are being rendered correctly. So, the error you are getting comes from the fact that when a user submits your form they receive a pop-up modal box to confirm the action. 

Therefore, instead of trying to fire the confirm button, try just to find it in the document. This will be enough to know that the component has rendered correctly. 

Try this :  expect(getByText(/confirmbutton/i)).toBeInTheDocument(); (change the text to the button's text)